# Samba 4.8.3 homedirs can only be mapped and accessed if other = rwx

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, samba, home-directory

Problem:
user1 can map 6 shares normally.  Another share, homedir, is mapped
but gets the error message that "Windows cannot access \samba\homedir:
You do not have permission to access \samba\homedir."

user2 can map 5 shares normally, but the 6th share and homedir 
are mapped but get the error message that 
"Windows cannot access \samba[homedir|staff]:
You do not have permission to access \samba[homedir|staff]."

Both users have identical group memberships in both the Windows AD 
and linux NIS.

This problem occurs on Windows 7 and 10, macOS, and linux using smb:.

Other users have different combinations of what works and what doesn't and 
they are in the correct groups for the shares they are trying to map.
In all cases, the homedir is mapped but not accessible.  The homedirs have
permissions 700.  I can map the share and look into it only if "other" has rxw
access, namely 707.  I can also edit, create, and save files, but *only* if "other" is rwx.  Even 007 works.  This is not a useful setting for a private home directory.

I've tried force user = %U and valid users = %U to no avail. I've also tried 
valid users = DOMAIN\%S (with the correct domain name).

Another samba server which runs a very old version of samba (4.05, downloaded
and compiled from samba.org and installed with default locations) which does
not use winbindd (or sssd) does work in all cases.

The problem samba server in question was able to map all the shares with proper
permissions a couple of weeks ago, but somehow lost the ability to do so 
even though no changes were made to the samba configuration or to the 
Windows Domain Controller during that time.
Restarting services and rebooting the samba server and domain controller did
not fix the problem.

I need to be able to use a modern version of samba, not 4.05 which I compiled myself from samba.org, and it needs to be able to map shares and see the permissions from NIS and the ZFS file shares.

---

Here is the setup:

File servers (all are on the same subnet, and no software firewalls):
FreeBSD 12 (NSFv4) with ZFS

This is where all file shares and home directories are.

aclmode = discard

aclinherit = restricted

(these are the default settings)

Logon server for linux machines:  Solaris SunOS 5.8 running NIS
The NIS realm is DEPT

Samba Server:  Scientific Linux 7.6 running Samba 4.8.3 
(acquired from the SL repositories via yum install samba)
set up as a Member Server of our domain (BIO)
selinux is turned off
It is joined to the domain and kinit and klist show that
tokens are being issued.

```
[root@samba ~]# kinit user1@BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU
Password for luser1@BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU: 
[root@samba ~]# klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:0
Default principal: user1@BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
04/25/2019 17:40:08  04/26/2019 03:40:08  krbtgt/BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU@BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU
    renew until 05/02/2019 17:40:02
```

It is running smbd, nmbd, and winbindd

wbinfo -ug shows the users and groups from the AD server
wbinfo -n username shows the AD SID for the user
wbinfo -D BIO shows the correct info for the AD domain

Windows Domain Controller Servers:  Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 2012

The same usernames exist in both NIS and AD

### Configuration files on the samba server:

/etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
 [global]
    log level = 2
    realm = BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    netbios name = SAMBA
    workgroup = BIO
    security = ADS
    password server = ad1.bio.dept.wisc.edu
    domain master = No
    local master = No
    os level = 0
    preferred master = No
    machine password timeout = 0
    disable spoolss = Yes
    load printers = No
    printcap name = /dev/null

    template shell = /usr/bin/bash
    # trying to set homedir location
    template homedir = /ua/%U

    winbind enum groups = Yes
    winbind enum users = Yes
    winbind offline logon = Yes
    winbind refresh tickets = Yes
    winbind rpc only = Yes
    winbind use default domain = Yes

    idmap config BIO: range = 40000-50000
    idmap config BIO: backend = rid
    # tried backend = ad and it didn't work either
    idmap config BIO: default = yes
    idmap config * : range = 100000-299999
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

    log file = /var/log/samba/log_%m_%a_%R
    max log size = 50

    follow symlinks = yes
    unix extensions = no
    wide links = yes
    inherit acls = yes
    map acl inherit = yes
    short preserve case = yes
    preserve case = yes
    oplocks = False
    level2 oplocks = False
    posix locking = no
    include = /etc/samba/smbshares.conf
```

In /etc/samba/smbshares.conf the homedir section is

```
[homedir]
    comment = Home Directories
    path = %H
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    public = no
    writable = yes
    guest ok = no
    printable = no
```

Testparm gives:

Loaded services file OK.

Server role: ROLE_DOMAIN_MEMBER

/etc/krb5.conf:

```
# Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
# there is currently nothing in the below directory
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 default_realm = BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU = {
  kdc = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:88
# admin_server = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:749
  default_domain = BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU
 }

[domain_realm]
 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU
 bio.dept.wisc.edu = BIO.DEPT.WISC.EDU
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:     files winbind nis
shadow:     files nis
group:      files winbind nis
hosts:      files nis dns
bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
```

/etc/pam.d/system-auth:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so
# add winbind
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so cached_login use_first_pass

# add pam_access.so
account     required      pam_access.so
# account     required      pam_unix.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so
# add pam_winbind
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_winbind.so cached_login
# add pam_succeed
account     requisite     pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup    [sysadmins]

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nis nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so
# add winbind
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so cached_login use_authtok

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

/etc/pam.d/password-auth:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so
# add winbind
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so cached_login use_first_pass

# add pam-access.so
account     required      pam_access.so
# account     required      pam_unix.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so
# add winbind
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_winbind.so cached_login
# add pam_succeed for user ingroup
account     requisite     pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup [sysadmins]

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nis nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
# add winbind
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so cached_login use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

/etc/security/pam_winbind.conf:

```
[global]
# turn on debugging
;debug = no

# turn on extended PAM state debugging
;debug_state = no

# request a cached login if possible
# (needs "winbind offline logon = yes" in smb.conf)
;cached_login = yes

# authenticate using kerberos
;krb5_auth = yes

# when using kerberos, request a "FILE" krb5 credential cache type
# (leave empty to just do krb5 authentication but not have a ticket
# afterwards)
;krb5_ccache_type =

# make successful authentication dependent on membership of one SID
# (can also take a name)
;require_membership_of =

# password expiry warning period in days
;warn_pwd_expire = 14

# omit pam conversations
;silent = no

# create homedirectory on the fly
;mkhomedir = no
```

/etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# PAM configuration for the sshd service
#
#auth
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
# Add winbind
auth       sufficient   /lib64/security/pam_winbind.so     try_first_pass

# account
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
# Add winbind
account    sufficient   /lib64/security/pam_winbind.so

# password
password   include      password-auth
password   required     pam_unix.so     no_warn try_first_pass
# Add windbind
password   sufficient   /lib64/security/pam_winbind.so  no_warn try_first_pass

# session
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
# Add winbind
session    required     /lib64/security/pam_mkhomedir.so debug skel=/etc/skel umask=0077
```